# Find number of physical ports for a NIC card (Ethernet card) on Linux system?

Tags: linux, networking

How do I find the number of ports for a NIC card?   A NIC card may have 1 or 2 or 4 ports on it. Is there any specific command that will show the number of ports and for which port the cable is connected etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can list all your NIC name with :

```
ip link show
```

then install `ethtool` and try:

```
sudo ethtool -p <NIC Name>
```

This should make your NIC led blink.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

`ip -o link show`

To list number of ports available per NIC

```
lspci | grep Eth | awk -F ':' '{print $NF}' | uniq -c

      2  Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
      4  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Comment: That helps. In your output we have 2 ethernets one has 2 ports & other has 4 ports on it. But how do I know to which port the cable is configured?

Comment: ls -l /sys/class/net/    will show which ethernet port is associated to which ethernet name.